# PHP - How to store distinct values so that while loop will not reiterate previous loops

Tags: php

I want my array to echo out only distinct values.
Here are my php codes so far:

```
$get_con = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE from_id='$my_id' OR to_id='$my_id' ");
$last_select_id = "";

while ($run_con = mysqli_fetch_array($get_con)) {
  $from_id = $run_con['from_id'];
  $to_id = $run_con['to_id'];

//This just ensures that it echos the other person's id and not my own
  if ($from_id == $my_id) { 
  $select_id = $to_id;
  } else {
  $select_id = $from_id;}

//Trying to save the iterations
  if ($select_id != $last_select_id) {
  $last_select_id = $select_id;
  echo "$select_id<br/>";
  }
}
```

For example, my array has: 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4.

My codes will return as: 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4

I want: 1, 2, 3, 4

The problem is that 2 and 4 are being repeated twice.
The statement, "if ($select_id != $last_select_id) {" is stopping "1" from being repeated twice in the beginning. This means that my if statement can only store $last_select_id only once for the previous iteration. I've searched for two days but couldn't find an answer. I would appreciate any help! Thank you.

Comment: Are you able to sort before you iterate?

Comment: I tried sorting before iterating, but I couldn't as the while loop will not store the variable. 

(Maybe) helpful information:
I'm trying to make a messaging system. So the id corresponds to a person. When you enter the messaging page you see the list of users you’ve talked to. Once you click on that user, you’ll see all the previous conversations. I want to show the user’s name just once.

Comment: In that case I'd just use the `SELECT DISTINCT` statement in your SQL query. You'll only get distinct ID's.

Comment: Unfortunately, the id is auto increment so it is already distinct. There are four columns in my array: "id" (primary and auto-increment), "from_user", "to_user", "message". Every time a user sends a message, mysql with first query for the user logged on (my_id) and then show the other user (select_id). Sometimes "my_id" is the one sending the private message (from_user) but sometimes, "my_id" is the one receiving a private message (to_user). I'm in a situation where I can't use distinct because the values are on two different columns (to_user and from_user)

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT` would still return distinct values, despite the fact that they are coming from 2 different columns. Rather than returning `1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4`, it would return `1,2,3,4`.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your answers! @BlackHatSamurai, I implemented the SELECT DISTINCT on line: $get_con = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT DISTINCT from_id, to_id FROM messages WHERE from_id='$my_id' OR to_id='$my_id' ");... It lessened my results by half, but there are still repeating numbers (but at least it's a maximum of two repeating - which is better than before!) I looked into adding "FOREACH statements" (it only query one row ***foreach ($run_con as $select_id){ 
    echo "<hr>$select_id";
    })***, "GROUP_CONCAT()" (couldn't make it work), and "array_unique()" (couldn't make it work)

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of approaches you can use.

In PHP, you can create an array, and place each entry into the array as it's returned/echoed/whatever.

```
$array = array( 1,1,2,3,4,4,5 );
$seen = array();

foreach ( $array as $arr ) {
    if ( !in_array( $arr, $seen )) {
        echo $arr.PHP_EOL;
        $seen[] = $arr;
    }
}
```

Of course, it's probably better to not have duplicate entries in the array, anyway.  In PHP, you can use array_unique() for that:

```
$array = array( 1,1,2,3,4,4,5 );
$array = array_unique( $array );
foreach ( $array as $arr ) echo $arr.PHP_EOL;
```

But probably even better than THAT is to simply not have duplicates in your array to begin with.  Look at "SELECT DISTINCT " in your SQL for that....

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a function for this

`array_unique($array)`

Documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php).

In your case it would be

```
$temp_array = array_unique(mysqli_fetch_array($get_con));
foreach($temp_array as $temp) {
    *stuff*
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `SELECT DISTINCT` statement in my query:

```
//I'm assuming you have a column called "id"
$get_con = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT DISTINCT id FROM messages WHERE from_id='$my_id' OR to_id='$my_id' ");
```

Info on `SELECT DISTINCT` can be found here: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-distinct.aspx

From there you can just do the following to output all the id's:

```
foreach($id in $get_con){ 
    echo $id
}
```

You can also adjust for needs as you see fit.

Comment: I'm in a situation where I can't use distinct because the values are on two different columns... Please view the comment below the main question for more information :)

Comment: @KhoaTran it would still work. `SELECT DISTINCT` takes conditional inputs. Take a look at the link I provided and give it a try ;)